# Trying to find a android native View by nativeID

Tags: react-native

I'm trying create a custom android UI component to expose some android native View props (nextFocusRight/nextFocusDown/Up/Left etc). For now I am just extending the `ReactViewManager` and exposing the props I need.

In order to get this to work I want to set the `nativeID` on the react native js component and then be able to find a reference to it on the native View. I am trying to do this using `ReactFindViewUtil.findView` helper but I'm not able to get this to work.

Here is what have got so far:

```
class ReactViewManagerCustom : ReactViewManager() {
    var mCurrentActivity: Activity? = null
    override fun getName(): String = "ReactViewManagerCustom"

    override fun createViewInstance(context: ThemedReactContext): ReactViewGroup {
        mCurrentActivity = context.currentActivity
        return ReactViewGroup(context)
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "nextFocusRight")
    fun setNextFocusRight(view: View, @Nullable nativeId: String) {
        var viewGroup = mCurrentActivity?.window?.decorView?.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
        var targetView = ReactFindViewUtil.findView(viewGroup, nativeId)
        targetView?.let {
            view.nextFocusRightId = it.id
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `viewGroup` passed to the `findView` call doesn't contain the expected View anywhere in the hierarchy. The viewGroup is a `FrameLayout` which contains a single child `ReactRootView` but it has no children.

How do I go about finding a View anywhere in the hierarchy using the `nativeID`? Is there a better way to go about this? I'm brand new to android so I might be looking at this the wrong way so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried the same and worked for me.